# A Raspberry Pi via ethernet connection apt-get doesnt work hangs at 0% "waiting for headers" any ideas?

Tags: ethernet, raspberry-pi, apt

So I have a Raspberry Pi connected to a host pc via ethernet. The host PC  is connected to the internet, so is the Pi:

```
$ ping www.google.de -c 5
PING www.google.de (216.58.214.35) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fra15s09-in-f35.1e100.net (216.58.214.35): icmp_seq=1 
ttl=53 time=42.6 ms

64 bytes from fra15s09-in-f35.1e100.net (216.58.214.35): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=51.6 ms

64 bytes from fra15s09-in-f35.1e100.net (216.58.214.35): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=224 ms

64 bytes from fra15s09-in-f35.1e100.net (216.58.214.35): icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=29.3 ms

64 bytes from fra15s09-in-f35.1e100.net (216.58.214.35): icmp_seq=5 ttl=53 time=38.1 ms


--- www.google.de ping statistics ---

5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms

rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 29.360/77.286/224.621/74.017 ms
```

But when I do `apt-get update` I got this:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://archive.raspbian.org jessie InRelease                                                                                                               
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease [22.9 kB]                                                                                            
Hit http://archive.raspbian.org jessie/main Sources                                                 
Hit http://archive.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Sources                                                         
Hit http://archive.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Sources                                                        
Hit http://archive.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Sources                                       
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease                                      
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main armhf Packages         
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib armhf Packages
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free armhf Packages
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi armhf Packages
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en   
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en      
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en
Get:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease [22.9 kB]                                                                                                                                                    
Get:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease [22.9 kB]
100% [3 InRelease 0 B/22.9 kB 0%]
```

And here it stops or with `apt-get install`:

```
0% [Waiting for headers]
```

Fun thing is that if I use `vncserver/viewer` and start a console this way, it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you use if not `vnc`?

Comment: just the terminal with: ssh -Y

Comment: Are you connecting the Pi with WiFi or Ethernet? It looks a like a poor WiFi connection.

Comment: the pi is connected via ethernet to a PC and the PC is connected to the internet with wifi.

Comment: Try checking or turn off firewalls on RP.  It blocks different ports and may block one used for download.  I have had no problem with this but have adjusted my firewalls.

Comment: What is running in the PC to give internet access to the Ethernet network, while still allowing access from the PC to both the internet and the Pi? You haven't said what OS the PC is running, so I can't guess.